# I need to convert cocoa powder into unsweetened chocolate squares

Tags: substitutions

So if I  need 2/3 of a cup of cocoa powder and I don't have it how much semi sweet chocolate squares do I need in place of the cocoa

Comment: What are you going to make? Depending on the intended use, the answer may be somewhere between “it doesn’t work” and “to taste”...

Comment: Is it sweetened cocoa or unsweetened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I substitute chocolate chips for cocoa powder in my frosting?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35142/can-i-substitute-chocolate-chips-for-cocoa-powder-in-my-frosting)

Comment: Your title is asking the opposite of your question body. Can you clarify, including specifying what it is you're trying to make? As Stephie noted, the answer could be wildly different depending on the purpose.

Comment: The question is about *substitution* but heading says *convert* (like you might be making chocolate squares using cocoa). And then as @Marti says you flip in in the body of the question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substitute unsweetened baker's chocolate for powdered cocoa in cake recipe](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25618/how-to-substitute-unsweetened-bakers-chocolate-for-powdered-cocoa-in-cake-recip)

Answer (score 2):

One ounce of semi-sweet chocolate equals 3 tablespoons cocoa powder + 1 tablespoon butter or oil + 1 tablespoon of sugar (from [The Cook's Thesaurus](http://www.foodsubs.com/Chocvan.html))

2/3 cup = 10 2/3 tablespoons

If your recipe calls for 2/3 cup cocoa powder and you want to substitute semi-sweet chocolate, you will need to reduce the butter or oil in your recipe by 3.5 tablespoons and the sugar by 3.5 tablespoons (10 2/3 divided by 3 equals 3.5)

You will also likely incorporate semi-sweet chocolate differently than you would cocoa powder, depending on what it is you are making. For example, for brownies, instead of mixing the cocoa powder directly in as in [Alton Brown's recipe for Cocoa Brownies](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/cocoa-brownies-recipe-2085484), you may need to melt the chocolate in a double-boiler, let it cool, then proceed with instructions such as those for [Ghirardelli's Classic Chocolate Brownies](https://www.ghirardelli.com/classic-chocolate-brownies-rec1048) that calls for semi-sweet chocolate.